# Is dynamically changing Schema in Rails possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create new tables, add/delete columns from within my app. Is this possible?

Comment: Which database are you using..?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do whatever the application database user can do to the database with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute. For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE people ADD name VARCHAR(60);')
```

But, if you add a column to a table, the corresponding attribute for the column will not be available in the ActiveRecord class until you restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. Rails has to run migrations to get the tables in to the database. This requires that the server has be stopped and restarted after the migrations. You don't want this scenario in production.

Dynamic forms would accomplish what I believe you are after.

In short you make fields of a model a separate model. For instance

```
class Car 
  has_many :car_fields
end 

class CarFields
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Then you can make a form where the users can add and remove fields when the add a car to the database.

This is great explained by Ryan Bates here http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms

I think you need a subscription to watch it. I you don't have one, get one. Railscasts is great!